# Mass of NGC 1097 Galaxy

Tags: astronomy, mass, specific-reference, galaxies, observational-astronomy

I've been looking all over the internet for this and can't seem to find a reference.  Can anyone refer me to a paper citing the mass of [NGC 1097](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGC_1097) based on luminosity?

Comment: This might be better posed on Astronomy.SE

Comment: Hi @Kyle Kanos: Concerning retagging: It seems that this should be res. recom. tag rather than spec. ref. tag, cf. their tag wikis.

Comment: @Qmechanic: res. recom. is for resources that explain topics, spec. ref. is for papers/books that, e.g., "first discovered X". OP wants a paper that gives the value of X, which seems to fit spec. ref. rather than res. recom. If you disagree, feel free to edit it the other way.

Comment: Admittedly not a big issue. Since @David Z was involved in formulating the tag wikis, I'm pinging him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1963) reports modelling of NGC 1097, and they use a figure of around $10^{10}$ solar masses. They cite a paper that isn't available online.

I have to confess this seems small to me. It's only 1% of the mass of the Milky Way.

Comment: [Crosthwaite 2002](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002PASP..114..929C) is available online ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between stellar mass and gravitating mass. 
The quoted Milky Way mass includes dark matter.

---

Despite searching in the literature, I have yet to find reliable apparent magnitudes and good distance estimates for NGC 1097.

The total Blue luminosity of this galaxy is near to Minus B-band absolute magnitude -21, but only ballpark estimates can be made from the existing data. NGC 1097 is significantly more luminous than our own Milky Way Galaxy!

Here is the best that I can do, insofar as estimating the distance and the absolute magnitude and the luminosity of NGC 1097:
http://www.iceinspace.com.au/forum/showthread.php?p=1164458

Unfortunately, NGC 1097 is one of many bright southern galaxies for which there are no "high accuracy"(+/- 10 percent) distance determinations using methods such as TRGB and Cepheids.

People are writing lots of papers on N1097 without having a good idea of how far away it is!!

---

A more accurate way to estimate the mass, in the form of stars, in a given galaxy, is to base the luminosity estimate of a galaxy on the Near-infrared magnitude, for instance the H or K band magnitude.

---

Sincerely yours,
Robert
alias madbadgalaxyman